# what is the line doing? is the address getting increased or is it both the address and value are being updated

Tags: c

```
char *_strcat(char *dest, char *src)
{
    char *temp = dest;

    while (*dest)
        dest++;

    while (*src)
        *dest++ = *src++; ====> this line

    *dest = '\0';
    return (temp);
}
```

I don't understand the line of code I specified above; does it update both the value and address of `dest`, or does it just update the value.and also what is the main logic here.I am lost!

Comment: In short, `*dest++ = *src++;` is essentially equivalent to `*dest = *src; dest += 1; src += 1;`

Comment: "_does it update both the value and adress of dest, or does it just update the value_" Can't you just print/debug and check what happens?

Answer (score 0):

The precedence of the `++` operator is higher than the `*` operator, but as `++` — in an expression — uses the old value of the operand, the part:

```
*dest++ = *src++;
```

first dereferences the `src` pointer, initializing the memory address pointed to by `dest`, then increments both the pointers by `1` to point to the next character.

In a loop, this copies the memory contents of `src` to `dest`.

It's the same as doing;

```
*dest = *str;
dest++;
str++;
```

Or

```
*dest = *src;
dest += 1;
src += 1;
```